# Magento MySql Query to fetch List of first time buyers

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, analytics

I Would like to produce a `MySql` Query to be execute on `sales_flat_order` table.
and to fetch a list of customers that has made their first order between dates.

```
select customer_id from sales_flat_order where 
created_at between '1/1/2013' and '30/1/2013'
and (this is the first time that the customer has made an order. 
     no records for this customer before the dates)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get every customer's earliest order date:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    MIN(entity_id) AS entity_id,
    MIN(increment_id) AS increment_id,
    MIN(created_at) AS created_at
FROM sales_flat_order
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Results:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| customer_id | entity_id | increment_id | created_at          |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|           1 |         1 | 100000001    | 2012-04-27 22:43:27 |
|           2 |        15 | 100000015    | 2012-05-10 14:43:27 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Note:** The above assumes that the smallest `entity_id` for a customer will match the earliest `created_at` for a customer.

Building on this, you can join with the orders:

```
SELECT o.* FROM sales_flat_order AS o
JOIN (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MIN(entity_id) AS entity_id,
        MIN(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM sales_flat_order
    GROUP BY customer_id
) AS first ON first.entity_id = o.entity_id
WHERE
    first.created_at BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-30';
```

Comment: Thank you Franklin. simple and quick

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
        'from' => '1/1/2013',
        'to' => '30/1/2013',
    ))
    ->distinct(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along this line. Made up some field names, so tweak to your structure.

```
select customer_id 
from sales_flat_order o1
where created_at between '1/1/2013' and '30/1/2013'
and Not Exist
(
    Select order_id    
    from sales_flat_order o2
    where o2.customer_id = o1.customer_id 
      And o2.order_id <> o1.order_id
      And o2.created_at < o2.created_at 
)
```